# Input/Textarea - Required string parameter is not present

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having issues with the above code recognizing the 'defaultpagination' variable. It keeps throwing the 'Required String parameter 'defaultpagination' is not present' message on the user interface. This is part of an edit screen showing a configurable setting.

The controller method is below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateSetting(
        @RequestParam("defaultpagination") String defaultPagination,
        @RequestParam("id") long id) {

        Setting setting = settingService.getOne(id);
        setting.setDefaultPagination(Integer.parseInt(defaultPagination));
        settingService.saveSetting(setting);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/settings/setting-listing");
}
```

The thymleaf html can be seen below.

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator" name="createSetting" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" th:object="${setting}" action="/settings/update">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="defaultpagination">Default Pagination</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="defaultpagination" type="number" th:field="${setting.defaultPagination}" placeholder="Enter default pagination" required="required" data-error="Pagination is required (maximum cannot exceed 100)" />
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                 </div>
                 <input type="hidden" th:rows="1" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" th:value="${setting.id}"/>
                 <br />
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
                 <br />
                 <br />
                 <br />
              </form>
```

What's interesting is that I can change the 'input' tag to a textarea tag and everything would work as normal (the defaultpagination gets recognized). However, I want to use the input for validation. In this case the input needs to be a number. In similar cases, I will need a phone number and email. Has anyone faced this same problem regarding the input/textarea tag in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to change the String defaultPagination in the controller to Integer (if you expect only integer as defaultpagination)

ie

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateSetting(
        @RequestParam("defaultpagination") Integer defaultPagination,
        @RequestParam("id") long id) {
```

Another solution is to use the pattern attribute of the input tag (permit only numbers not decimal points)

```
    <input class="form-control" name="defaultpagination" type="text" 
pattern="\d+" th:field="${setting.defaultPagination}" placeholder="Enter default
 pagination" required="required" data-error="Pagination is required (maximum cannot exceed 100)" />
```

Let me know if these worked for you

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked. I get the same message but in this case, saying that the integer 'defaultpaginatinon' is not present

Comment: @Albert As far as I see you don't need to upload a file so can you remove the "enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form and let me know if this changed anything